# Procedure with parameters in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

Why this procedure after adding parameters is not working?

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: As @Wernfried Domscheit has already mentioned, please, don't use screenshots to post your questions when you can type the code and error message within the proper tags to make it visible. This helps other users to search for error messages to look for answers to their own questions.
Besides, it's not a good practice to write your own code in the SYSTEM user, that is a user to perform administration work in the database, it's better to create a user with the convenient privileges (create and write in its own objects) and write your code there, so you have separated administration tasks and app

Answer (score 2):

No need for `IN OUT` parameters; `IN` would suffice (because of PLS_00363: SYSDATE can't be used as an assignment target while calling the procedure).

As you're manipulating parameters' values, I declared local variables for that purpose.

Also, `next_day` won't work with `7`; use day name (hence my `alter session` to set language to English so that I could use `SUNDAY` as day name).

(Didn't we already discuss that? Where did your previous question go? Right, here it is: [Function Next_Day in pl/sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70516101/function-next-day-in-pl-sql/70516168#70516168) ; why did you create another account?)

When fixed:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE liczba_niedziel (data_od  IN DATE,
  2                                               data_do  IN DATE)
  3  IS
  4     l_data_od  DATE;
  5     l_data_do  DATE;
  6     licznik    NUMBER := 0;
  7  BEGIN
  8     l_data_od := NEXT_DAY (data_od, 'SUNDAY');
  9     l_data_do := data_do;
 10
 11     WHILE l_data_od <= l_data_do
 12     LOOP
 13        l_data_od := l_data_od + 7;
 14        licznik := licznik + 1;
 15     END LOOP;
 16
 17     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 18        '...' || SYSDATE || ' - ' || l_data_do || '...' || licznik);
 19  END;
 20  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> EXEC liczba_niedziel(sysdate, date '2022-01-18');
...30.12.2021 - 18.01.2022...3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table plsql_profiler_runs
(
  runid           number primary key,  -- unique run identifier,
                                       -- from plsql_profiler_runnumber
  related_run     number,              -- runid of related run (for client/
                                       --     server correlation)
  run_owner       varchar2(128),       -- user who started run
  run_date        date,                -- start time of run
  run_comment     varchar2(2047),      -- user provided comment for this run
  run_total_time  number,              -- elapsed time for this run
  run_system_info varchar2(2047),      -- currently unused
  run_comment1    varchar2(2047),      -- additional comment
  spare1          varchar2(256)        -- unused
);

comment on table plsql_profiler_runs is
        'Run-specific information for the PL/SQL profiler';

create table plsql_profiler_units
(
  runid              number references plsql_profiler_runs,
  unit_number        number,           -- internally generated library unit #
  unit_type          varchar2(128),    -- library unit type
  unit_owner         varchar2(128),    -- library unit owner name
  unit_name          varchar2(128),    -- library unit name
  -- timestamp on library unit, can be used to detect changes to
  -- unit between runs
  unit_timestamp     date,
  total_time         number DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  spare1             number,           -- unused
  spare2             number,           -- unused
  --  
  primary key (runid, unit_number)
);

comment on table plsql_profiler_units is 
        'Information about each library unit in a run';

create table plsql_profiler_data
(
  runid           number,           -- unique (generated) run identifier
  unit_number     number,           -- internally generated library unit #
  line#           number not null,  -- line number in unit
  total_occur     number,           -- number of times line was executed
  total_time      number,           -- total time spent executing line
  min_time        number,           -- minimum execution time for this line
  max_time        number,           -- maximum execution time for this line
  spare1          number,           -- unused
  spare2          number,           -- unused
  spare3          number,           -- unused
  spare4          number,           -- unused
  --
  primary key (runid, unit_number, line#),
  foreign key (runid, unit_number) references plsql_profiler_units
);

comment on table plsql_profiler_data is 
        'Accumulated data from all profiler runs';

create sequence plsql_profiler_runnumber start with 1 nocache;
```